# Effective divisor linearly equivalent to an canonical divisor

Tags: algebraic-geometry, riemann-surfaces

If $A$ is an effective divisor of $deg(A)=g-1$, then there exists an effective divisor $B$, of $deg(B)=g-1$, such that $A + B \sim K$, where $K$ is a canonical divisor.

I understand that $deg (A + B) = deg (K) = 2g-2$. But how to justify that  $A + B \sim K$?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to show that $K-A$ is effective. That is, $H^0(K-A)\neq 0$. By Serre duality, this is same as $H^1(A)$. Riemann-Roch gives $h^0(A)-h^1(A)=0$, but $h^0(A)\neq 0$ and thus nor is $h^1(A)$.

Comment: Could you clarify what version of Riemann-Roch are you using here? Is it the one for curves or the higher dimensional version? OP has not really made it clear what the dimension of the ambient variety is…